# Kibana fields are non searchable

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I'm adding documents to an index "test_produit".

```
PUT test_produit/produit/3
{
  "nom": "NNZDCNIND",
  "ref": 1233322,
  "blabla": "bliblbi"
}
```

For some reason I don't understand, "nom" is a searchable field, but all the others aren't.

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: can you post your index mappings GET test_produit/_mappings ?

Comment: I solved it :) I had to re-initialise the search index pattern.